# Docker container listens to gitlab commits

Tags: python, git, docker, gitlab

I am in need of a docker container that listens to a particular `GitLab` repository and once any changes (mostly commits and pushes) have happened I need that container to pull the changes.

My scenario is, currently I have a docker container running `node` as the base image. It runs a `react js` front-end for an application. So every time I do some changes locally and `push`, I need that docker container to update the container with the latest changes and reflect that.

**This docker container runs in an amazon `ec2`**.

How can I do this? Is there a `python` package for `GitLab` ?

Comment: What you want to do is to setup a continuous deployment environment using gitlab's pipeline. You need to check [GitLab CI/CD documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/)

Comment: I have already set a `GitLab` pipeline. But I have some other jobs as well, so it takes some time for the pipeline to finish. I just need some simple, quick workaround for this.  @MickaelB.

Comment: @user13456401 Maybe you can set up another GitLab runner (that runs on Amazon) and configure pipeline to run a job on that runner (in parallel to other runners)

Comment: I will try that. Thanks. Can I register two GitLab runners in the same `ec2`? If so, can you provide some guidelines?

Comment: @user13456401 I don't have much experience with Amazon AWS, but it should run. Maybe this will help - https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws/ ? Here on SO should be someone who has more experience with Amazon...